# Double Free or Corruption error when re-sizing Priority Queue

Tags: c++, runtime-error, delete-operator

I've run into this error before, but the circumstances baffle me as I have run nearly this exact set of functions without having this issue.

Let me break it down:

The error is being caused by the resize() private member function of a custom priority queue I am working on. It is all centered around de-allocating the pointer to the old queue array. Before I explain any further, let me list the handful of relatively small functions I've isolated the problem to.

```
void unfairQ::enqueue(int val)
{
    if (isFull())
        resize();   

    numElements++;
    ageCount++;

    heapArr[numElements].data = val;
    heapArr[numElements].age = 1;
    heapArr[numElements].priority = heapArr[numElements].data;

    heapifyUp(numElements);

    if (ageCount == 100) {
        heapSort();
        ageCount = 0;
    }

    return;
}

bool unfairQ::isFull()
{
    return (numElements == capacity);
}

void unfairQ::resize()
{
    int newCap = (capacity * 1.5);
    queueNode *tempHeap = new queueNode[newCap];

    for (int i = 1; i <= numElements; i++) {
        tempHeap[i].data = heapArr[i].data;
        tempHeap[i].age = heapArr[i].age;
        tempHeap[i].priority = heapArr[i].priority;
    }
    // delete [] heapArr;
    capacity = newCap;
    heapArr = tempHeap;
    return;
}
```

The commented out line in the resize function is the one causing problems. If I do delete the pointer to the array I get the "double free" error, however if I remove that line I get a "free(): invalid next size (normal):" if I enqueue enough values to require a second resize().

Please let me know if you need any more information or if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Where does the free error come from if you remove the delete []? You must have some other free that causes the double free error. Maybe you should add enough code to be runnable/testable.

Comment: The only other function with a delete [] is the desctructor, but I don't get a "free error" when I remove the delete. As mentioned in the original post when I remove that delete [], it functions properly unless I have to resize twice in which case I get the error:  "free(): invalid next size (normal):"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using your array with indexes starting from 1, c++ uses indexes starting from 0. This can cause a buffer overflow.

For example:

If `capacity` is currently 5 (so `heapArray can have 5 entries) and`numElements`is currently 4, your`isFull`will return`false`(correctly), however your`enqueue`code then increments`numElements`(from 4 to 5) and attempts to write to`heapArray[5]` which is out of bounds and may overwrite some other memory.

Solution: start your indexes from 0, e.g. in the `enqueue` function, increment `numElements` *after* you write the data `heapArray[numElements]`

Comment: I'm using indices 1-size because the zeroeth index doesn't work in a binary heap which is what im using for data storage. I don't believe that is the issue, but I will double check to make sure there isn't a '<' where there needs to be a "<=" etc

Comment: @user3776749 Faking 1-based arrays in C++ is many times a source of memory corruption.  There are often too many moving parts to keep track of when you do things this way.

Comment: I can see that now. Is there any other way to implement a binary heap? All my functions work with it as such A[i/2] for the parent and A[i*2 + 1] and A[i*2] for the children. And that doesn't work if i can be 0;

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, while I was referencing/incrementing/decrementing all the indices correctly and calling the appropriate functions at the appropriate times, I was operating under the notion that I was working with indices 1-size, but in the constructor (something I hadn't glanced at for a while) I'd initialized numElements as 0 which broke the whole gosh darned thing.

Fixed that and now everything is hunky dory!

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Well, as I stated in the comment, faking 1-based arrays almost always results in a bug showing up somewhere.  That's why it is not a good idea to go down that road.  I'm sure a binary heap or any other data structure can be implemented using the natural way that C++ indexes arrays.